# How to implement object composition in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am new to Rails framework. I am trying to create a non ActiveRecord backed model class with following composite structure -

```
{
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Bangalore",
        "state" : "KA"
    },
    "images" : [
        "image-path-1",
        "image-path-2"
        "image-path-3"
    ],
    "facilities" : [
        {
            "name" : "abcd"
        },
        {
            "name" : "xyz"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I go around creating this composite model ?

Comment: This is basic object oriented programming in Ruby. I suggest looking up tutorials on writing classes in Ruby, and familiarize yourself with the basic concepts of object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

In rails you would be looking to implement what is known as a "Form" model.  Being new to rails this will introduce you to many strange 'semi-advanced' topics but the following is what you want to do.  I recommend looking up any methods/modules you haven't seen since there is a bit of magic rails uses in the background here (validation callbacks etc):

First choose a class name...based on the attributes you provided I'll call the class Company.

```
    class Company

include ActiveModel::Model #This gives you access to the model methods you're used to.
include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks #Needed for before_validation

attr_accessor :address
attr_accessor :images
attr_accessor :facilities #This accessor method basically just says you will be using "facilities" as a virtual attribute and it will allow you to define it.

#Add validations here as needed if you're taking these values from form inputs

def initialize(params={}) #This will be executed when you call Company.new in your controller
  self.facilities=params[:facilities]
  #etc for the other fields you want to define just make sure you added them above with attr_accessor or you wont be able to define them.  Attr_accessor is a pure ruby method if it's new to you.
end



  def another_method
   unless self.facilities.somethingYourCheckingForLikeNil?
     errors.add(:facilities, "This failed and what you checked for is not here!"
   end
  end

end
```

Then in your controller if you follow the normal flow you would have something like:

```
def new
  company = Company.new
end

def create
  company = Company.new(company_params)
  #whatever logic here for saving what you may want saved to a database table etc...
end


private

def company_params
   params.require(:company).permit(:facilities, :address, :whatever_other_params_etc)
end
```

Without more information I can't give you a full example however this should get you on track to learn more about "Form Models".